# Chat in nodejs, messages repeat according to the number of current users in chat

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

im trying to create a chat using nodejs for a project, the problem is that when i send a message and there is more than 1 user on the chat it repeats the message, for example [(visual example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CB2R1.png), if i have 4 users in the chat it prints the message 4 times.
This is the code im using
socketio.js

```
var Messages = require('../controllers/chat_message')
var socket_io = require('socket.io');
var io       = socket_io();
var socketio = {};
socketio.io  = io;
var users = [];
 io.on('connection', function(socket){
    
    console.log('A user connected');
console.log(`Socket connected ${socket.id}`)

    Messages.getpreviousMsgs()
        .then(dados =>socket.emit('previousMessage', dados))
        .catch(erro =>res.status(500).jsonp(erro)) 
        
        socket.on('sendMessage', data => {
            console.log(data);
            Messages.create(data)
                .then(dados =>console.log("Saved"))
                .catch(erro =>res.status(500).jsonp(erro))
        });
    socket.on('join', function (user){
       socket.username = user.username;
       users.push(socket.username);
       io.emit('user joined', { 'username': user.username, users:users });
    });

    
    socket.on('typing', function (msg) {
        io.emit('typing', { 'message': msg.message, 'username': msg.username });
    });

    socket.on('new_message', function (msg) {
         io.emit('chat message', { 'message': msg.message, 'username': msg.username });
    });
    
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
        users.splice(users.indexOf(socket.username), 1);
        io.emit('user disconnected', { 'username': socket.username });
    });
     
 });
 
module.exports = socketio;
```

chat_script.js

```
    var username = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2,8); 
    socket.emit('join', { username: username });
    
    socket.on('user joined', function (data) {
        $(".js-userjoined").html(data.username + ' Joined chat room');
        console.log(data.users);
         $.each(data.users, function(index, user) { 
              console.log(user);
             $(".js-usersinchat").append('<span id ='+user+'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>'+user+'</strong></span>');
         });
     });
     
     socket.on('user disconnected', function (data) {
        $("#"+data.username).remove();
     });
     

       socket.on('previousMessage', function(messages){
                    for(message of messages){
                        $('#messages').append('<div class="row message-bubble"><p class="text-muted">'+message.author+'</p><p>'+ message.message+' </p> </div>');
                    }
            });
   

    //an event emitted from server
    socket.on('chat message', function (data) {
        var string = '<div class="row message-bubble"><p class="text-muted">' + data.username+'</p><p>'+data.message+'</p></div>';
        if (data.username.length && data.message.length){
                        var messageObject = {
                            author:data.username,
                            message: data.message,
                        };
                    socket.emit('sendMessage',messageObject);
                  }
      $('#messages').append(string);
    });

 

    $(function () {
        var timeout;

        function timeoutFunction() {
            typing = false;
            socket.emit("typing", { message: '', username: '' });
        }
       $("#sendmessage").on('click', function () {
         var message = $("#txtmessage").val();
         $("#txtmessage").val('');
         $('.typing').html("");
         socket.emit('new_message', { message: message, username: username });
       }); 

       $('#txtmessage').keyup(function () {
           console.log('happening');
           typing = true;
           socket.emit('typing', { message: 'typing...', username: username});
           clearTimeout(timeout);
           timeout = setTimeout(timeoutFunction, 2000);
       });
   });

    socket.on('typing', function (data) {
        if (data.username && data.message) {
            $('.typing').html("User: " + data.username + ' ' + data.message);
        } else {
            $('.typing').html("");
        }
    });

var typing = false;
var timeout = undefined;

function timeoutFunction(){
  typing = false;
  socket.emit(noLongerTypingMessage);
}
```

I hope i was clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try remove this line:

```js
socket.emit('sendMessage',messageObject);
```

Here on `chat_script.js`:

```js
    //an event emitted from server
    socket.on('chat message', function (data) {
        var string = '<div class="row message-bubble"><p class="text-muted">' + data.username+'</p><p>'+data.message+'</p></div>';
        if (data.username.length && data.message.length){
                        var messageObject = {
                            author:data.username,
                            message: data.message,
                        };
                    // THIS LINE BELOW:
                    socket.emit('sendMessage',messageObject);
                  }
      $('#messages').append(string);
    });
```

Comment: thank you for the time and solution, problem solved